# Simple Drawing in Firemonkey's TImage priorities

Tags: graphics, firemonkey

A very strange thing is happening to me (at least it is strange to me...).
I've placed some TImages over a Firemonkey form, and I have assigned some images to their bitmaps.
They are showing OK.
Then I have added another TImage, which is empty.
I'm trying to draw some shapes inside the TImage.Canvas, and it seems working fine, in the sense that I can see the TImage with the shapes for a very short period, after that the TImage with my drawings is deleted by the form and only those "preloaded" TImages remain visible.
The code is working, because I can see the TImage for a tenth of a second, then it disappears, simply cancelled by the form background.
What am I doing wrong?
This is the code

```
Procedure NDrawCircles(var IMGTarget: TImage; xc, yc, Radius: Integer; MyPen: MyPenType);
var
   MyRect: TRectF;
   CustPattern: Array [0 .. 7] of Single;
   i: Integer;
   MyDash, bsc : Integer;
   x1, y1, x2, y2 : Extended;
   V: Single;
Begin
   bsc := IMGTarget.Canvas.BeginSceneCount;
   if bsc = 0 then
      IMGTarget.Canvas.BeginScene;
   IMGTarget.Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
   IMGTarget.Canvas.Stroke.Color := MyPen.Color;
   IMGTarget.Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := MyPen.Thickness;
   IMGTarget.Canvas.Stroke.Dash := MyPen.Dash;

   x1 := xc - Radius;
   y1 := yc - Radius;
   x2 := xc + Radius;
   y2 := yc + Radius;
   MyRect := TRectF.Create(x1, y1, x2, y2);
   bsc := IMGTarget.Canvas.BeginSceneCount;
   IMGTarget.Canvas.DrawEllipse(MyRect, MyPen.Opacita);
   bsc := IMGTarget.Canvas.BeginSceneCount;
   if bsc > 0 then
      IMGTarget.Canvas.EndScene;
end;

Procedure TConfiguraDignita.DrawBaseModel;
Type
   TCircleso = Record
        XC,YC : Single;
        R : Integer;
       MyPen : MyPenType;
   end;
Var i : Integer;
    Circles : Array[1..7] of TCircleso;
Begin
   for i := 1 to 7 do
   begin
      Circles[i].XC := TargetIMG.Width / 2;
      Circles[i].YC := TargetIMG.Height / 2;
      Circles[i].MyPen.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
      Circles[i].MyPen.Color := claBisque;
      Circles[i].MyPen.Dash := 1;
      Circles[i].MyPen.Opacita := 1.0;
   end;
   Circles[1].MyPen.Thickness := 4.0;
   Circles[2].MyPen.Thickness := 4.0;
   Circles[3].MyPen.Thickness := 4.0;
   Circles[4].MyPen.Thickness := 2.0;
   Circles[5].MyPen.Thickness := 2.0;
   Circles[6].MyPen.Thickness := 2.0;
   Circles[7].MyPen.Thickness := 2.0;

   Circles[1].R := 600;
   Circles[2].R := 550;
   Circles[3].R := 500;
   Circles[4].R := 450;
   Circles[5].R := 400;
   Circles[6].R := 350;

   For i := 1 to 7 do
      NDrawCircles(TargetIMG, Trunc(Circles[i].XC), Trunc(Circles[i].YC), Circles[i].R, Circles[i].MyPen);

   TargetIMG.Repaint;

End;
```

Inside the FormShow there is nomy a call to the DrawBaseModel procedure.
The reading of the bsc is done to see if there is something in the BeginScene stack after the beginescene call.

Comment: Please show the code with which you are drawing on the empty `TImage`.

Comment: Done. In the FormShow method there is only the call to the DrawBaseModel  Procedure.

Comment: I HAVE FOUND IT. It was missing the call inside the Form.OnPaint event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate and draw on the `Bitmap` of the `TImage`. So first create the `Bitmap` e.g. in the `OnCreate` event of the form;

```
procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create(trunc(Image1.Width), trunc(Image1.Height));
end;
```

And then draw on that bitmap:

```
begin
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Chocolate;
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 3.0;
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawLine(TPointF.Create(5,5),TPointF.Create(180,180),1);
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I HAVE FOUND IT. It was missing the call inside the Form.OnPaint event.

Thanks however for the availability.

Comment: Good! I was guessing something else, but obviously wrong. I leave my answer  for now, but will remove it later.

Comment: No Tom, don't remove your comment. And I will not remove my question, at the future memory to look for the obvious, before to go searching into the "exotic".